# How can I stop HTML being output to the compiled app.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I am using Webpack 2 for my portfolio website, but it's not an SPA - therefore, the intention is not to output everything into my bundled JS.

I have a few entry points for the `.pug`, `.scss` and `.js` files. Like so:

```
entry: {
  app: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/app.pug'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
  ]
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'js/[name].js'
}
```

However, when looking at the source for the `app.js`, I see the rendered HTML from my `.pug` files.

[image]

For the `.pug` compiling, I'm using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. I guess the easiest way for me to explain what's going on is to show you the `webpack.config.babel.js` file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import SvgStorePlugin from 'external-svg-sprite-loader/lib/SvgStorePlugin';
import bourbon from 'bourbon';
import neat from 'bourbon-neat';

const extractScss = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/[name].css',
  allChunks: true
});

const config = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/app.pug'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'pug-html-loader',
            options: {
              pretty: false,
              exports: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['es2015']
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              progressive: false,
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
                quality: '90',
                speed: 5
              },
              mozjpeg: {
                quality: 90
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'external-svg-sprite-loader',
            query: {
              name: 'svg/sprite.svg',
              iconName: '[name]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractScss.extract([
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins() {
                return [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'Explorer >= 9', 'Android >= 4']
                  })
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [
                bourbon.includePaths,
                neat.includePaths
              ]
            }
          }
        ])
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new SvgStorePlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Portfolio',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      hash: true,
      template: 'src/pug/app.pug',
      filetype: 'pug',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    extractScss
  ]
}

process.traceDeprecation = false;

export default config;
```

I don't see any CSS in the `app.js` bundle and the entry point is setup just the same, so might it have something to do with the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` itself? Perhaps I'm not understanding how this works correctly and my configuration is wrong.

I'm new to Webpack (coming from Gulp), so please bear with me if the answers to my questions seem rather obvious.

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**
For reference, my project structure is as follows:

[image]

And I would call an image from my `.pug` file in `/pug/components/example.pug` with a path like `img(src="../images/example.jpg")`. This worked prior to removing `.pug` as an entry point in the Webpack config as user Tatsuyuki suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add the template as an source:

```
app: [
  // path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/app.pug'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
]
```

Instead, specify the template option for HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.pug'
})
```

[Reference](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md)

Comment: Whilst that does remove it from the app.js, now any image references in the .pug files do not come through. i.e. src in image tags etc. Any ideas there at all? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify where the assets are placed and how you are referencing them.

Comment: Thank you - I have updated my question at the bottom with a screenshot of the project structure and explanation on the paths I was using. If I run dist or dev server, these images are no longer being picked up. No errors or warnings either.

Comment: Please try removing the redundant options block for `pug-html-loader`. I have no idea if it will solve your issue or not.

Comment: I'm afraid removing that just makes matters worse! The rendered HTML is output to the screen in plain text.